# Is there a way to update log4j to latest version?

Tags: log4j, upgrade, log4j2, log4javascript, log4jdbc

1.How can we update log4j from older versions to latest version
2.What needs to be changed in pom.xml
3.What artifacts needs to be updated
4.Which verison of log4j is stable
5.What is the source to upgrade log4j to latest version

Comment: Are you asking about upgrading Log4j 2.x or migrating from Log4j 1.x to Log4j 2.x? For the latter follow the [migration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).